# Trying to run WordPress on localhost?

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP server and bitnami WordPress on my Ubuntu machine. I want to run a WordPress on my localhost but the following error occurs:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30
>   mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Comment: Hi, can you access the root folder of your website or you have trouble running XAMPP? You mean that even with the empty folder you get an error?

Comment: can you please share your dir structure & url you are trying to access from?

Comment: xampp is running without any trouble and also i have installed word press  but when trying to run local host those error are occur

Comment: in your control panel you can see an `Admin` button when you start Apache click it and check if you can see the dashboard

Comment: Check if you have put your files in htdocs folder for inside Xampp

Comment: Just curious, what `URL` are you using to access the localhost in your browser's address bar?

Comment: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

WWW server don't give You what Your browser is asking for. It could be caused by inproper web files privilages or there are no files in web subdirectory where server expects them.